# Sum of arctans of trignometric expressions

Tags: trigonometry

Let $s_k=\sin\frac{2\pi(4k+1)}{4n}$ and $c_k=\cos\frac{2\pi(4k+1)}{4n}$ for some positive integer $n$. If $n=2007$ and $x=3$ , find $\tan \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \arctan(\frac{s_k}{x-c_k})$

I tried using complex numbers, since the sequences looked like roots of unity. Since $\arctan$ denotes the argument of a complex number, and $s_k$ and $c_k$ are the imaginary and real parts respectively of the 8028th roots of unity congruent to 1 (mod 4), the expression is the sum of the arguments of these roots of unity, except shifted over due to the 3 in the denominator. How can we proceed from here (Or is this not the best way to do the problem?)

Comment: Hint: $\arctan(a)+\arctan(b) = \arctan(\frac{a+b}{1-ab})$ so $\tan(\arctan(a)+\arctan(b)) = \frac{a+b}{1-ab}$ (modulo $\pi$).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I tried pairing up the numbers (like $\frac{s_k}{3-c_k}$ and $\frac{s_{n-1-k}}{3-c_{n-1-k}}$), but it doesn't seem like this can be simplified. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Here's some progress (maybe?): Let $w_k=c_k+is_k=\cos \frac{2\pi(4k+1)}{8028}+i\sin \frac{2\pi(4k+1)}{8028}$. Let $w_0=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{8028}}=w$. Then we have $w_k=w^{4k+1}$ Note that we have $s_k=\frac{w^{4k+1}-\overline{8028-w^{4k+1}}}{2i}$ and we can find a similar expression for $c_k$ Also note that we have $\overline{w^k}=w^{8028-k}$. Then the expression $\frac{s_k}{3-c_k}$ can be written as $\frac{w^{4k+1}-w^{8028-(4k+1)}}{i(6-w^{4k+1}-w^{8028-(4k+1)}}$

Comment: ^ Then I tried pairing the terms like I said in my first comment except it's ugly since the expressions don't come in conjugate pairs.